# mongoose can not connect mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use mongoose to connect mondb,i follow the mongoose offical site but it went wrong ,my package.json is`"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.4.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.5.10"`

and code is
    `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/web');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        // we're connected!
    });`
but it occurs error,log is
    `/home/develop/gitlab/web/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)`
What is wrong?

Comment: is mongod process running?

Comment: maybe another service like IIS running on localhost

Comment: i run mongo bu docker,and i use mongo-express to see it ,and i can create document and collection